# Как отобразить на экране полученное по tcp протоколу изображение в виде массива байтов?

Tags: tcp

Доброе время суток. Хочу сделать так, чтобы полученное по tcp протоколу изображение в виде массива байтов можно было отобразить , ну скажем, в ImageView андроид. Не могли бы Вы мне подкинуть идейку, или дать ссылку на хороший материал по этой теме?

Comment: TCP -- это транспортный протокол, обеспечивает только гарантию передачи пакетов. Поверх него работает протокол прикладного уровня -- неясно что вы для этого хотите использовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы распаковать картинку, содержащуюся в массиве:

```
byte[] data = ...
```

В Android:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
imageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

В JavaSE:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
...
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, попробую